# How do I set up this double integral problem? Find the volume below $z = r$, above the $x$-$y$ plane, and inside $r = 1 + \cos θ$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is what I have so far, but the book's answer is $\frac 49$.

\begin{align}
x & = r \cos(θ)\\
y & = r \sin(θ)\\
z & = z\\
r^2 & = x^2+y^2\\  
θ & = \tan^{-1}(y/x)\\
V & = \text{volume} \\
V & = \iint_R f(x,y) \, dx \, dy\\
V & = ∫^{θ_1}_{θ_0}∫^{r_1}_{r_0} f(r, θ) \, dr \, dθ \\
V & = ∫^{\fracπ2}_{-\fracπ2} ∫^{\cos θ}_0 r\, dr \, dθ\\
∫^{\cos θ}_0 r \, dr & = \left. \frac {r^2}2 \right|^{\cos θ}_0 = \frac {\cos^2(θ)}2\\
& ∫^{\frac π2}_{-\frac π2} \frac {\cos2(θ)}2 \,dθ
\end{align}

I can already tell this isn't correct.  I have also tried the inner integral from $0$ to $\pi$ and $0$ to $2\pi$.  I believe I am not setting up the integral properly and need assistance with that.  The section of the book this is coming from is:  [15.2 Double Integrals in Cylindrical Coordinates](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section15.02.html)

Comment: For your convenience, integrals are `\int_{a}^{b}`; many special functions follow `\name` like `\tan` for $\tan$ (proper typeface); most Greek letters follow `\Name` for upper cases and `\name` for lower cases, like `\Theta` for $\Theta$ and `\theta` for $\theta$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: (why has nobody pointed this out?) I believe the error is in treating dxdy as drdθ when it should be rdrdθ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what region we get from $r=1+\cos\theta$ It will be a heart-shaped curve, if $\theta : 0\rightarrow 2\pi$. We should now decide our integration-interval that we get by just looking at the region we are given. $r : 0 \rightarrow 1+\cos\theta$ and $\theta : 0\rightarrow 2\pi$.

Now between what functions are we suppose to calculate the volume. $z=r$ and xy-plane (i.e $z=0$)

Now we can setup the integral. (Dont forget that $dxdy=rdrd\theta$ )

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1+\cos\theta}(r-0)rdrd\theta \\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(1+\cos\theta)^3}{3}d\theta \\
=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^3\theta +3\cos^2\theta +3\cos\theta + 1d\theta \\
=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\sin^2\theta)\cos\theta +\frac{3}{2}(1+\cos2\theta) +3\cos\theta + 1d\theta = \frac{5\pi}{3}$

P.S I looked at the website at the answer if $r=1+\cos\theta$ is $\frac{5\pi}{3}$. But if u meant $r=\cos\theta$ you can use the same method

Answer (score 0):

The region is $R=\{(r,\theta,z)\in\mathbb R^3|0\le r\le2\cos \theta,-\frac{\pi}2\le \theta\le\frac{\pi}2,0\le z\le r\}$. By simmetry the volume $V$ of the region is given by
\begin{align*}
V&=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos \theta}(r)rdrd\theta\\[3pt]
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{8}{3}\cos^3\theta\,d\theta\\[3pt]
&=\frac{16}3\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\sin^2\theta)\cos \theta\,d\theta
\end{align*}